# Android application receive data from Computer

Tags: android, text, sms

I was wondering if there is a way to send a text from my PC using Internet to an Android application. I do not need to send a sms, i need to send a text who will be shown in that application.

Is there a way I could do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you have to use [Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=fo).

But you could also try [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/), there is a library for [Android](http://www.pubnub.com/devcenter), although I have never tried it myself.